# Laravel 4.1 Hash::make inconsistency

Tags: php, authentication, hash, laravel-4

I was trying to match hashed password from the database against password - hashed from the login form and it doesn't match no matter what.

Then I've done some consistency tests.

```
$password = Hash::make('secret');
echo $password;
```

I've been getting different results each time I refresh the page. Not like md5, it's consistent.

Am I missing something?

Or am I using/doing it wrong?

Why Hash::make produces inconsistent result with the same args?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct, and that's by design.

AFAIK, the function uses the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) php function, and defaults to the PASSWORD_BCRYPT flag, which

> PASSWORD_BCRYPT - Use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm to create the
>   hash. This will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the
>   "$2y$" identifier. The result will always be a 60 character string, or
>   FALSE on failure.

That means a salt is automatically generated at each call, and inserted *within* the generated string, which contains: an identifier for the algo (in this case, `$2y$`), the iteration cost (defaults to 12), the hashed password, and the generated random salt.

That means, thus, everytime you hash your password a new salt is created, therefore the string will always be different - even if the password is the same. That's *one* of the strengths over a simple md5 hash without salt.

To check it, you use Hash::check(), which uses the password_verify() php function, which analyses the hash, guess the algo used, takes, the embedded salt, and can therefore check if the procedure, given the same starting conditions, creates an identical hash.

**Edit**

Indeed, this is the method (in `Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher`)

```
 * Hash the given value.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @param  array   $options
 * @return string
 */
public function make($value, array $options = array())
{
    $cost = isset($options['rounds']) ? $options['rounds'] : $this->rounds;

    $hash = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => $cost));

    if ($hash === false)
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException("Bcrypt hashing not supported.");
    }

    return $hash;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. Great info. So, how can I compare hashed password in sql level? The only solution I see is get the password (query) then use Hash::check... to get the password, have to find record which matches the username. but i want two column search/match on my query.

Comment: I don't think you can do that at DB level, or it would be pretty hacky and difficult - usually it's done at processing level, I see no reason to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

```
Validator::extend('old_password', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    return Hash::check($value, Auth::user()->password);
});

$rules = array(
    'old_password' => 'required|old_password',
    'new_password' => 'required|confirmed'
);
$messages = array(
   'old_password' => 'wrong old password'
);
$validator = Validator::make($data = $input, $rules, $messages);
```